# No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of '**'?

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell code:

```
two :: Integer -> Integer
two i = toInteger(2 ** i)
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 6):

`(**)` requires floating point input based on the function signature:

```
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

`toInteger` on the other hand requires input that is integral in nature:

```
toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer
```

Therefore, you cannot reconcile the two the way you use it. That said, since you seem to be expecting integer input anyway, you might consider using `(^)` instead, like so:

```
two :: Integer -> Integer
two i = 2 ^ i
```

As @leftaroundabout correctly points out in the comments, `(^)` will fail for negative values of `i`. This can be resolved by checking for value and handling in an alternate manner, something like this:

```
two :: Integer -> Integer
two i = if i > 0 then 2 ^ i else floor (2 ** fromIntegral i)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `^` only works for non-negative exponents. If round-off to zero is desired, like `floor (2 ** fromIntegral i)` would give for negative `i`, then this needs to be handled with an extra clause.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for this. Do you mind if I add it into my answer?

Comment: There's also `^^`, whose result can be rounded.

Answer (score 2):

Use `^` instead:

```
two i = 2 ^ i
```

And then there is no need for to cast the result back to an Integral type.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this...

```
two :: Integer -> Integer
two i = toInteger(2 ** i)
```

...doesn't work is because you've declared `i` to be an integer, and if we look at the type of `(**)`...

```
Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

... all it's arguments are of the same type, and that type has to be an instance of the `Floating` type-class. `Integer` is not an instance of `Floating`. This is what "No instance of (Floating Integer)" means.

The simplest solution is to use `^` as ErikR suggests. It raises a number to an integral power.

```
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
```

If you want to work through using `**` to learn a bit more, keep reading.

---

So we need to convert your integer into a type which is an instance of `Floating`. You can do this with `fromIntegral`. If we do this:

```
two :: Integer -> Integer
two i = toInteger(2 ** fromIntegral(i))
```

...we still get a load of error messages complaining that various types are ambiguous. These aren't as clear as the first message, but the issue is the use of `toInteger` which becomes apparent if we look at it's type.

```
Prelude> :t toInteger
toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer
```

As we're passing the result of `**` to `toInteger`, and that is a `Floating`, not an `Integral`, `toInteger` is the wrong function. `round` is a better choice.

```
two :: Integer -> Integer
two i = round(2 ** fromIntegral(i))
```

This now works.